# Set variable from activity response Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

[image: Pipeline variables]

[image: Pipeline]

I have REST call in a Copy data activity which gives me a json response
My goal is to fetch the "hasNextPage" value and put it into the hasNext variable

I want to set it as a value in a "Set variable" activity that is connected to the "Copy data" activity, where I expected to acess the output in a way like this: @activity('Timesheets').output.data.timesheets.pageinfo.hasNext

I also want to be able to fetch the value of "cursor" from the last element in the "edges" array[]

I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this

Json response that I get from the Timesheets activity

```
[
{
"data": {
  "timesheets": {
    "pageInfo": {
      "hasNextPage": true
    },
    "edges": [
      {
        "cursor": "81836000243260.81836000243275.",
        "node": {
          "parameter1": "2019-11-04",
          "parameter2": "81836000243260"
        }
      },
      {
        "cursor": "81836000243252.81836000243260.81836000243275",
        "node": {
          "parameter1": "2019-11-04",
          "parameter2": "81836000243260"
        }
      }
     ]
   }
  }
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this, the output of an copy data activity don't have a data property you can access.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview

Copy Activity are made for copying large data, and it doesn't copy all rows in one go.
So it would not make sense to have an output dataset for a Copy Activity.

If your response from your REST service contains limited element, you can use an Web Activity to consume the REST service.
This have an output dataset you can access.
Followed by a foreach activity to iterate the data set. Remember to take into consideration parallel vs sequential iteration of you data set in the foreach activity.

Note in your service response, you get an array of "data" objects, so you need to address the first "data" element.